# regex stop following certain character

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract some antimicrobal data from a laboratory database.

The organism name code and sensitivity/resistance pattern are all contained in a single string under `result_text`.

The organism is always 6 captial letters long and always has an asterix at the beginning.

The antimicrobial names are always 3 capital letters long, followed by either an R or r, for resistant, S or s, for sensitive, etc for various coding.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  sample_date_time = as_datetime("2021-01-01 03:00:00"),
  sample_no = "BC11001",
  result_text = "[<*ESCCOL/2/I   /AMPR/>=32/AUGR/16/>]"
)


df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(result_text,  delim = "/") %>% 
  mutate(
    org = str_extract(result_text, "\\*([A-Z]{6})", group = 1),
    antimicrobial = str_extract(result_text, "(?<!\\*)[A-Z]{3}"),
    sens = str_extract(result_text, "([A-Z]{3})(R|r|S|s|I|i|P|p|N|n)", group = 2)
  ) 
#> # A tibble: 8 × 6
#>   sample_date_time    sample_no result_text org    antimicrobial sens 
#>   <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>       <chr>  <chr>         <chr>
#> 1 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "[<*ESCCOL" ESCCOL SCC           <NA> 
#> 2 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "2"         <NA>   <NA>          <NA> 
#> 3 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "I   "      <NA>   <NA>          <NA> 
#> 4 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "AMPR"      <NA>   AMP           R    
#> 5 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   ">=32"      <NA>   <NA>          <NA> 
#> 6 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "AUGR"      <NA>   AUG           R    
#> 7 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "16"        <NA>   <NA>          <NA> 
#> 8 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   ">]"        <NA>   <NA>          <NA>
```

I am trying to extract for example the `AMPR` in row 4 into separate columns `AMP` and `R`.

However I want the regex to ignore matching if the string is of the pattern *[A-Z]{6}, such as *ESCCOL in row 1.

I thought using a negative look back for * would solve the problem but as you can see in the reprex, SCC is still being extracted into the antmicrobial column, when I actually want an NA.

Could someone point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong? After reading many posts/websites, still a bit confused about it.

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

An approach with `str_extract`. Note that I modified the example by adding lower case *sens* to the string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(result_text, "/") %>% 
  mutate(org = str_extract(result_text, "\\*.*([A-Z]{6})", group = 1), 
         antimicrobial = str_extract(result_text, "^[A-Z]{3}"),
         sens = str_extract(result_text, "^[A-Z]{3}([RrSsIiPpNn])", group = 1))
# A tibble: 15 × 6
   sample_date_time    sample_no result_text org    antimicrobial sens 
   <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>       <chr>  <chr>         <chr>
 1 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "[<*ESCCOL" ESCCOL NA            NA   
 2 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "2"         NA     NA            NA   
 3 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "I   "      NA     NA            NA   
 4 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "AMPR"      NA     AMP           R    
 5 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   ">=32"      NA     NA            NA   
 6 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "AUGR"      NA     AUG           R    
 7 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "16"        NA     NA            NA   
 8 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "><*ESCCOL" ESCCOL NA            NA   
 9 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "2"         NA     NA            NA   
10 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "I   "      NA     NA            NA   
11 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "AMPs"      NA     AMP           s    
12 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   ">=32"      NA     NA            NA   
13 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "AUGr"      NA     AUG           r    
14 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "16"        NA     NA            NA   
15 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   ">]"        NA     NA            NA
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(sample_date_time = structure(1609470000, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), sample_no = "BC11001", 
result_text = "[<*ESCCOL/2/I   /AMPR/>=32/AUGR/16/><*ESCCOL/2/I   /AMPs/>=32/AUGr/16/>]"), 
row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: thanks. above works well and I learnt a couple of ways of making my regex better. I hadn't realised that Hadley Wickham's `r4ds` book has a whole section on regex. Looking at it again I got things completely the wrong way round. I actually want a positive look back if I want to use that method: 
`mutate(
    org = str_extract(result_text, "(?<=\\*)[A-Z]{6}"),
    antimicrobial = str_extract(result_text, "^[A-Z]{3}"),
    sens = str_extract(result_text, "(?<=[A-Z]{3})[RrSsIiPpNn]")
  )`

Comment: @Ollie When learning all about regex always keep in mind that ["now you have two problems"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems) :)

Comment: Thanks @andre-wildberg, discovering that regex is very fiddly

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ifelse()` with `test = !str_detect(result_text, "\\*")` to
only extract the three letters when no asterisk exists in `result_text`.

```r
df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(result_text,  delim = "/") %>%
  mutate(
    org = str_extract(result_text, "\\*([A-Z]{6})", group = 1),
    antimicrobial = ifelse(
      !str_detect(result_text, "\\*"),
      str_extract(result_text, "[A-Z]{3}"),
      NA
    ),
    sens = str_extract(result_text, "([A-Z]{3})(R|r|S|s|I|i|P|p|N|n)", group = 2)
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 × 6
#>   sample_date_time    sample_no result_text org    antimicrobial sens 
#>   <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>       <chr>  <chr>         <chr>
#> 1 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "[<*ESCCOL" ESCCOL <NA>          <NA> 
#> 2 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "2"         <NA>   <NA>          <NA> 
#> 3 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "I   "      <NA>   <NA>          <NA> 
#> 4 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "AMPR"      <NA>   AMP           R    
#> 5 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   ">=32"      <NA>   <NA>          <NA> 
#> 6 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "AUGR"      <NA>   AUG           R    
#> 7 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   "16"        <NA>   <NA>          <NA> 
#> 8 2021-01-01 03:00:00 BC11001   ">]"        <NA>   <NA>          <NA>
```

Comment: thanks. this is a nice way of thinking about how to do it using more tidyverse